# Does MacOS store information locally about external drives?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, external-disk, spotlight, metadata

I used a borrowed Mac to transfer sensitive data directly between two USB thumb drives. Ideally, I'd  like to not leave a single trace of the files and transfers on the borrowed Mac, but I understand that a modern OS might store a lot of tiny bits of information anywhere and everywhere. What are these on MacOS? (In my case, specifically, MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra)

I noticed that I couldn't safely eject the drives because Spotlight were indexing them for a pretty long time. But as far as I have understood, these indexes are *only* placed on the external drives themselves, and not anywhere on the Mac. Is this assumption correct?

In short:

- which processes might locally store information of externally mounted drives,
- what kind of information are they storing, and
- how can I "clean up" before giving the Mac back to its owner?

Comment: The data might be cached in memory; It's possible the filenames might be held somewhere, but I doubt the data is. Worth a restart, certainly.

Comment: In case Finder holds onto information like `Recently Used`, it might be prudent to never access the disk using Finder, and always perform any actions on the contents via command line only.

Comment: There's a spot in the Finder plist file in the Preferences directory where it stores the name and location (on the desktop) of every drive you connect.